# setting flag for validating fields failing

Tags: jquery, css

I have a couple of text boxes in the page and I am trying to do some validations on blur of the field. If validation fails, error is displayed and the field is highlighted. This is working correctly. If any error is present, teh form should not be submitted, else it should submit teh form. But now I am facing some problem assigning the flag. Now even if all the field validations are correct, the flag is always returned as false.

Can some body please help me to reset the flags correctly.

Below is my code

```
var validatorFlag = true;
var indFlag = 0;

var validators = {
    allowaplhawithaposonly:function(val) {
        return /^[a-zA-Z'\s]+$/i.test(val);
    },
    allowaplhanumwithaposonly:function(val) {
        return /^[\w'\s]+$/i.test(val);
    },
    allownospace: function (val) {
        return !/\s/.test(val);
    }
};

$('#submit_form .required').blur(function () {
    var input = $(this);
    var classReturn = true;

    input.next('ul.innererrormessages').remove();
    input.removeClass('required_IE');
    if (!input.val()) {alert("no val");
                       input.removeClass('valid');
                       input.addClass('required_IE');
                       var $msg = $(this).attr('title');
                       input.after('<ul class="innererrormessages"><li>'+$msg+'</li></ul>');
                       validatorFlag = false;
                      }
    else{alert("val present");
         if(this.className) {
             var classes = this.className.split(/\s+/);
             for(var p in classes) {
                 if(classes[p] in validators) {
                     classReturn = classReturn && validators[classes[p]] (input.val());
                 }
             }alert("classReturn "+classReturn);
         }
         if(classReturn == false){
             input.removeClass('valid');
             input.addClass('required_IE');
             var $msg = input.attr('title');
             input.after('<ul class="innererrormessages"><li>'+$msg+'</li></ul>');
             validatorFlag = false;
             indFlag = 1;
         }
         else{
             if(indFlag != 1){
                 validatorFlag = true;
             }
             else{
                 validatorFlag = false;
             }
         }

        }alert("validatorFlag "+validatorFlag); //This is always returning false

});

$('#submit_form').submit(function() {
    if(validatorFlag)
    {
        returnValue = true;
    }
    else{
        returnValue = false;
    }
    return returnValue;
});
```

I need to check if all the classes for a particular field is validated correctly or not. Only if all the validations for all the fields are correct, validatorFlag should be true. Now even though the validations are correct, validatorFlag  is returned as false. SO somewhere I need to reset the flag. I am not able to identify this. Can somebody please guide me?

Comment: I'd reset the value at the beginning of the validation function, i.e. assume that everything is ok before you start the validation process. However, unless you have a very good reason for coding validation from scratch, you'd be better off using [jQuery validation plugin](http://jqueryvalidation.org/)

Comment: Hi RAzvan.thats how I am also doing..But the flag returns false, even after all the validations are correct..Can u have a look into my code and tell me what I am doing wrong?

Answer (score 0):

the reason you get false when everything is ok is that you never reset the indFlag (whatever that is). You set it once at the beginning an then it get's set to 1 when a validation fails.
You should reset it at the beginning of the function.
Take a look at this [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/4VYb7/1/) I've put up with your code.

However you have a flaw in your algorithm. Think about this situation: you go to the first field put a wrong value, and then go to the next 2 fields and put correct values. When you hit submit the validation is true because you only take in account the validation for the last field (the last blur).

You should also make a validation for all the fields on submit. Something like this:

```
var validatorFlag = true;
var indFlag = 0;

var validators = {
    allowaplhawithaposonly:function(val) {
        return /^[a-zA-Z'\s]+$/i.test(val);
    },
    allowaplhanumwithaposonly:function(val) {
        return /^[\w'\s]+$/i.test(val);
    },
    allownospace: function (val) {
        return !/\s/.test(val);
    }
};


$(document).ready(function(){
    $('#submit_form .required').blur(function(){
        validatorFlag = true;
        indFlag = 0;
        validateField($(this));
    });

    function validateField(input){
        var classReturn = true;

        input.next('ul.innererrormessages').remove();
        input.removeClass('required_IE');
        if (!input.val()) {alert("no val");
                           input.removeClass('valid');
                           input.addClass('required_IE');
                           var $msg = input.attr('title');
                           input.after('<ul class="innererrormessages"><li>'+$msg+'</li></ul>');
                           validatorFlag = false;
                          }
        else{alert("val present");
             if(input.attr("class")) {
                 var classes = input.attr("class").split(/\s+/);
                 for(var p in classes) {
                     if(classes[p] in validators) {
                         classReturn = classReturn && validators[classes[p]] (input.val());
                     }
                 }alert("classReturn "+classReturn);
             }
             if(classReturn == false){
                 input.removeClass('valid');
                 input.addClass('required_IE');
                 var $msg = input.attr('title');
                 input.after('<ul class="innererrormessages"><li>'+$msg+'</li></ul>');
                 validatorFlag = false;
                 indFlag = 1;
             }
             else{
                 if(indFlag != 1){
                     validatorFlag = true;
                 }
                 else{
                     validatorFlag = false;
                 }
             }

            }alert("validatorFlag "+validatorFlag); //This is always returning false

    }

    $('#submit_form').submit(function() {
        validatorFlag = true;
        indFlag = 0;
        $('#submit_form input[type=text]').each(
                function(){
                    validateField($(this));
                   }
       );
        if(validatorFlag)
        {
            returnValue = true;
        }
        else{
            returnValue = false;
        }
        return returnValue;
    });
});
```

You can see it in this [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/4VYb7/8/) (UPDATED).

Comment: Hi Razvan..Thanks for looking into this..I checked ur fiddle. In that also, if I put a wrong value for first field and correct value for the other two fields, ideally it should return false. But its returning true..Can u try placing an alert for the alert(returnValue); and check?

Comment: You're right. I forgot about the 'this' inside the function (it should be replaced with 'input' - the function param). Also this.className -> input.attr("class"). I've updated the answer and the fiddle link.